# computing histogram using hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, histogram

I have a csv file of integers that encodes (r,g,b,a) values for an image and I'd like to compute 4 histograms for each of r, g, b, and a. Can I write a single map reduce job to do that in Hadoop?

For example given input file:

```
1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4
```

I would like to get histogram output to be:

```
r[1] = 2   r[i] = 0 for all other i's
g[2] = 2   g[i] = 0 for all other i's
b[3] = 2   b[i] = 0 for all other i's
a[4] = 2   a[i] = 0 for all other i's
```

the actual output file is another csv file that should look like:

```
0, 2, (253 0's for red), 0, 0, 2, (252 0's for green), 0, 0, 2, (251 0's   for blue), 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, (250 0's for alpha)
```

Comment: Could you rewrite your example with exact(possible) output values for the input provided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can.

1. In the mapper first parse the input to identify the channel.
2. Use the channel as the key (r, g, b, a) and the magnitude as the value. In your example: (r, 1), (g,2)... (a,4).

   3. In the reducers create arrays with length of 255 (one for each channel) initialized with zeroes.
   4. For each input, increment the cell related with the magnitude in one (in the appropriate array)
   5. Write in the output the values for each array. In the  **cleanup** method of the reducer.

If you use 4 reducers and create a partitioner that send each channel to a different reducer then in each reducer you only need to create one array and in the output you will get each histogram in a different file. Instead to use the letter of the channel you can encode them as 1,2,3,4 and use the key to select the reducer. Or use only one reducer where you will need to generate the four arrays or a 4 X 255 matrix and write the 4 histograms in only file.